# FFmpeg - make white background semi-transparent

Tags: ffmpeg

If an image is a typical non-transparent jpeg with white background. Is it possible to make the output background semi-transparent? I mean just the white, while other colors would remain opaque.

Comment: Have you done any research by chance? Maybe a web search for "ffmpeg convert color to transparent" or something like that? If so, what did you find and why didn't it work? If not, could you perhaps spend 10 minutes searching the web as I think people have encountered this issue before. Of course, if you find something and you can't get it to work, feel free to [edit] your question and focus on the part that doesn't work.

Comment: jpg is not capable of transparency, you'd have to use png.

Comment: @Tetsujin of course, I was referring to Source format being jpeg.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke lol I hope you realize searches like that take us to pages like this. People have high standards for convenience/digestibility of information these days

Comment: @pete I don't follow. Yes, obviously that phrase leads to this question, but it also leads to many more, existing questions with answers. Instead of someone googling that and typing that out in the answerbox below, why wouldn't the OP spend 10 minutes looking for it? It's [step 1 of asking a question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask). And sure, if the found commands don't make sense, or don't work (anymore) then asking the same question *and mentioning the research* is perfectly valid as then the answer could focus on a particular detail, actually adding information.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke This question/answer were perfect for my use case. There is literally no way I could've found the answer to my question faster, than landing on this page. I suspect if they'd done all the due diligence they wouldn't have asked the question. And we'd be missing tons of these time-saving "shortcuts" on the internet.

Comment: "*suspect if they'd done all the due diligence they wouldn't have asked the question.*" In the hypothetical case they would've found an answer to the question, and you have the same question, why would you not be able to find the same answer as OP did? And do I understand correctly that volunteers should duplicate information, in slightly different wording, such that it is easier to find for others?

Answer (score 5):

```
ffmpeg -i input.jpg -vf colorkey=white:0.3:0.5 out.png
```

Change `0.3` to `0.01` if you want only white(#ffffff) to be affected, without close colors.

Change `0.5` to whatever transparency amount you want, `0.0` will be fully transparent.

More info [here](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#colorkey).

***UPDATE*:**

Try this for a semi transparent background:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=c=white@0.5:s=1920x1080,format=rgba -i input.jpg -shortest -filter_complex "[1:v]colorkey=white[ckout];[0:v][ckout]overlay[out]" -map "[out]" out.png
```

This command generates a semi transparent white background first, and then overlays the input image on top of it (while also changing all its white pixels to be fully transparent like in my original answer). You might need to change the generated background resolution from 1920x1080 to match your image resolution.

Comment: This gave 100% transparent areas, my issue is being able to replace white with semi-transparency, e.g. 50% transparent white.

Answer (score 1):

```
magick input.jpg -fill "rgba(255,255,255,0.5)" -opaque #ffffff out.png
```

If you only need to convert images and not videos, [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/) is probably a better tool. Change the last fill value (`0.5`) to the amount of transparency you want. You can also change the background color itself to a different color than white by changing the first 3 values.

What you want to do is possible with FFmpeg too, but more difficult. I updated my FFmpeg answer with a working solution.